# Where does WordPress store version number?

Tags: wordpress-version

Easy question. Where does the self-hosted WordPress store version information?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you need to get the wordpress version in your script, there is a global variable:

`$wp_version` (right now it's something like `'3.1-RC3-17376'`)

It contains the wordpress version.

If you need to acquire if from a file, you can read it from `/wp-includes/version.php`:

```
function getWPVersion() {
    $path = '/path/to/wp-install';
    include $path.'/wp-includes/version.php';
    return $wp_version;
}
```

### Wordpress Version Variables

There is more information available in that file:

- `$wp_version` - The WordPress version string ('3.1-RC3-17376')
- `$wp_db_version` - Holds the WordPress DB revision, increments when changes are made to the WordPress DB schema (17056)
- `$tinymce_version` - The TinyMCE version string ('3393')
- `$manifest_version` - Holds the cache manifest version ('20111113')
- `$required_php_version` - Holds the required PHP version ('4.3')
- `$required_mysql_version` - Holds the required MySQL version ('4.1.2')

Answer (score 5):

The codex says its in wp-includes/version.php.

Answer (score 2):

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'getWPVersion' );

function getWPVersion() {

    echo $GLOBALS['wp_version'];

}
```